# Opening already opened file on Windows CE

Tags: c#, file, windows-ce

I have annoying problem with files. I develop soft on Windows CE which works with another piece of hardware. This hardware have physical memory (like pendrive) and this pendrive is visible from my device. Now I want to open one txt file on this memory and edit it. I know that that other piece of hardware opens that file all the time and monitore it.

I have little Notepad program which I downloaded, I can use it to edit that file anytime I want and hardware response in correct way. 
But if I want to open and edit that file from my program I get UnauthorizedAccessException. I know that this file is opened by another hardware but that notepad gets its job done so it is possible. I was trying many combinations to open file:

simple one:

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("path");
```

another:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, 
                    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
    ...
}
```

And I tried few combinations of FileMode and FileAccess and FileShare values. Now what should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to open the file from your application while you already have it open in Notepad?

Comment: What's the little Notepad program? Show us the link.

Comment: Can you make it sure that the text file has write permissions? Because as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh(v=vs.110).aspx), theis error occurs only when the file you are trying to write has read-only access. Maybe, the location of the file may prevent it from write permissions.